# How many ways to iterate a map in java? why iterat a mai if we have already for loop?

Tags: java

One can iterate through a `SortedMap` by using the iterator from `myMap.entrySet().iterator()`. But does this iterator preserve the ordering of the sorted map object ?

The SortedMap interface does not have its own methods to iterate through the entries. What is the standard way to iterate ordered through the entries?

Comment: Set does not preserve order, only lists preserve order.

Comment: @Sam The `Set` returned by `SortedMap#entrySet()` has an ordering.

Comment: Sam, that's not entirely correct.  The Set interface does not imply any iteration order of its subclasses, but implementers of SortedSet do imply a sorted iteration order.  Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html for more

Answer (score 1):

> One can iterate through a SortedMap by using the iterator from myMap.entrySet().iterator(). But does this iterator preserve the ordering of the sorted map object ?

Yes. See [the javadocs for SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

> This order is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views (returned by the entrySet, keySet and values methods).

---

> The SortedMap interface has no own methods to iterate through the entries. What is the standard way to iterate ordered through the entries ?

The usual trick is to use `entrySet()`, and iterate on those `Map.Entry` objects. For instance:

```
for (Map.Entry<K,V> entry : theMap.entrySet()) {
    K entryKey = entry.getKey();
    V entryValue = entry.getValue();
    // do whatever with them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, **yes**. Iterating via the `entrySet` will preserve order.

You can use the Java enhanced foreach loop:

```
for(final Entry<K,V> entry : myMap.entrySet(()) {
    //do something with entry
}
```